# Why don't <a> elements inherit size of child elements

Tags: html, css

I have very very very simple html, normally everything in HTML seems to work as it should, but in this case, it doesn't.  I would think that the size of an a tag should inherit a child image tag.  But in the case below, the sizes are different.

html:

```
<a href="."><img src="some image"></a>​
```

css:

```
a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

img {
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
​
```

Why does the `<a>` not inherit the size of the image?  (see: http://jsfiddle.net/49ykj/)

This occurs in both Firefox and Chrome so far, so I'm assuming it happens in all browsers.  This is a bug?  Why shouldn't it be a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `a` is an inline element while `img` is an inline-block element. Change the css `display` attribute of an `a` element to be inline-block and you will notice that they have the same size.

It's not a bug. Its just the nature of css and the fact that most browsers initialize the two elements css attributes in that way.